# dynamic add form field in flutter

Tags: forms, flutter

[I want this in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poov1.jpg) but I did not get add phone number when click on `[+]` button. When I've called Phone widget I got this error:

> W/AccessibilityBridge(16228): can't invoke getChildId with reflection

below is my code:

```
RaisedButton(
          child: Text(
            '+',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black26,width: 1.0,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
          onPressed: () {
            Phone();
            print('add phone is pressed');
          },
          color: Colors.white,
        ),

  class Phone extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          contentPadding:
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.1),
          ),
          filled: true,
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.phone,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 20.0,
          ),
          labelText: 'Phone Number',
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15.0,
              height: 1.5,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 61, 61, 1)),
          fillColor: Color(0xffD2E8E6),
        ),
        maxLines: 1,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are applying completely wrong logic here. You can't directly return `widget` in an widget `onPressed()` function.

example abstract of your code to add TextFormField:

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => new _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<Widget> _phoneWidgets = List<Widget>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text(
          '+',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black26, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _phoneWidgets.add(Phone(
              fieldName: 'Phone Number',
            ));
          });
        },
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 30),
          child: Column(
            children: List.generate(_phoneWidgets.length, (i) {
              return _phoneWidgets[i];
            }),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class Phone extends StatelessWidget {
  String fieldName;
  Phone({this.fieldName = ''});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.1),
          ),
          filled: true,
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.phone,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 20.0,
          ),
          labelText: fieldName,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15.0,
              height: 1.5,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 61, 61, 1)),
          fillColor: Color(0xffD2E8E6),
        ),
        maxLines: 1,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply it really solve my problem

Comment: Now, how can I get the value in each dynamically created fields?

Answer (score 0):

I edited the accepted answer to add getting the value in each dynamically created field. I added dynamically created textfield controllers.

```
class DynamicTextFieldPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DynamicTextFieldPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DynamicTextFieldPageState createState() => _DynamicTextFieldPageState();
}

class _DynamicTextFieldPageState extends State<DynamicTextFieldPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Phone> _phoneWidgets = <Phone>[];
  List<String> listOfTextEntries = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Dynamic Fields "),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Text(
          '+',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: const BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black26, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            //add Phone objects dynamically here while setting up a controller in there.
            _phoneWidgets.add(Phone(
              fieldName: 'Phone Number ${_phoneWidgets.length + 1}',
              controller: returnController(
                  "phoneController ${_phoneWidgets.length + 1}"),
            ));
          });
        },
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 30),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: List.generate(_phoneWidgets.length, (i) {
                    return _phoneWidgets[i];
                  }),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: MyButtonStyles(width: 120, height: 38)
                          .myElevatedButtonStyle(),
                      child: const Text('Submit'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        showTextFieldEntries();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextEditingController returnController(String controllerName) {
    final controllerName = TextEditingController();
    return controllerName;
  }

  //You can see the list of text entries from here.
  void showTextFieldEntries() {
    //listOfTextEntries = _phoneWidgets.map((i)=>i.controller.text.trim()).toList();
    _phoneWidgets.map((i) {
      //i.controller.text.trim();
      print("these are the listOfTextEntries ${i.controller.text.trim()}");
    }).toList();

    //print("these are ${listOfTextEntries[0]}");
  }
}

class Phone extends StatelessWidget {
  final String fieldName;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const Phone({Key? key, this.fieldName = '', required this.controller})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, bottom: 10.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
          enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.1),
          ),
          filled: true,
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.phone,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 20.0,
          ),
          labelText: fieldName,
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15.0,
              height: 1.5,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 61, 61, 1)),
          fillColor: const Color(0xffD2E8E6),
        ),
        maxLines: 1,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```